# Does the Azure AI Translator API offer the capability to display alternative translations for entire sentences?

Tags: microsoft-translator, azure-ai-translator

I'm using the Azure AI Translator API to translate sentences. For instance, when I translate the sentence "Hello my friends how are you" into Spanish, I receive the translation "hola amigos como estan". Is it possible for the API to display alternative translations for the same sentence, such as "hola mis amigos como estan" or "hola amigos como estais"? I'm aware that this is possible for words using the dictionary lookup method, but I'm unsure if this applies to entire sentences as well?

I have thoroughly reviewed the entire documentation of the Azure AI Translator API to ensure that I have understood all relevant information. According to the documentation, it should be possible to translate entire sentences. Based on this information, I attempted to translate entire sentences using the API. However, my developer reports that this is not working.

Comment: @Microsoft could you please answer to my question. Here ist the documentation text, why i think you can display alternative sentences: Dictionary lookup (alternate translations)
With the endpoint, you can get alternate translations for a word or phrase. For example, when translating the word "sunshine" from en to es, this endpoint returns "luz solar," "rayos solares," and "soleamiento," "sol," and "insolación." LInk: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/Translator/translator-text-apis?tabs=csharp#dictionary-lookup-alternate-translations